# How to modify JQuery Image Cropper to keep the cropping area same for images with different dimensions?

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery image cropper which works perfectly fine. But the cropping area changes as per the image dimensions.

Like, if I'm to take an image with **5000x2812** dimensions the cropper area looks like the below screenshot: (please note the scrollable height of that cropper div. I had to scroll to the image to crop it actually)

[image]

Now, if I'm to take an image with **150x150** dimensions the cropper area looks like the below screenshot: (please note that the image adjusted inside the cropper div with no scrollable height)

[image]

**My code goes like this:**

```
<div class="upload_div_child_body_attachments">
    <div class="upload_div_child_body_attachments_image">
        <input type="file" form="feed-post" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" id="image" onchange="previewFile()" name="image" class="upload_div_child_body_attachments_file_image"/>
        <input type="hidden" form="feed-post" name="image_cropped" id="image_cropped" />
        <i class="fa fa-image upload_div_child_body_attachments_image_icon"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="upload_div_child_cropped_image"></div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropper/2.3.0/cropper.js'></script>
<script>
var recorte = $('.img-container > img');
recorte.cropper({
  movable: false,
  zoomable: false,
  rotatable: false,
  scalable: false
});

function previewFile() {
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
   $('img').show(); 
   recorte.cropper('replace',reader.result);
   console.log("test");
  }
  if (file) {
    console.log("test2");
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log("test3");
  } else {
      console.log("test4");
   recorte.cropper('replace','');
   console.log("test5");
  }
  
  $("#misc_overlay").css("display","block");
  $(".upload_div_image_crop_slide_up").animate({ top: "30%"}, 300);

}

$('.salvar').click(function(){
    temp = recorte.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL(); 
    $(".upload_div_child_cropped_image").prepend('<img src="' + temp  + '" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:90%; height:auto;padding:5%;" />')
    $("#image_cropped").val(temp);
    $(".upload_div_image_crop_slide_up").animate({ top: "100%"}, 300);
    $("#misc_overlay, .upload_div_child_body_attachments").css("display","none");
});

$(".upload_div_image_crop_slide_up_header_cross").click(function(){
    $(".upload_div_image_crop_slide_up").animate({ top: "100%"}, 300);
    $("#misc_overlay").css("display","none");
});
</script>
```

**Working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harish3693/Lf19nwmo/) of the same**

My only objective is to load the image in the cropper div without any scrollable height no matter the image dimensions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to set a max-height of the image by css ? Can you make a working exemple ?

Comment: @SKJ Here's the fiddle bro https://jsfiddle.net/harish3693/Lf19nwmo/

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you please take a look at this one..

Comment: The JS Fiddle appears to have HTML from two pages. How should we replicate the issue properly? What steps should be taken and what have you tried?

Comment: You may want to review the following options: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/main/README.md#mincropboxwidth

Comment: This method appears to allow you to sett he Crop Box dimensions: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/main/README.md#mincropboxwidth